# 'PostListView' object has no attribute 'views'

Tags: python, django

Lo que quiero hacer es que una entrada tenga un contador de visitas pero no logro implementarlo correctamente.

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return 'detail/%s' % self.pk
```

Mi problema esta en get_context_data() creo, pero no entiendo porque ListView no tiene los atributos del *model*.

**views.py**

```
class PostListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = 'home.html'
    queryset = Post.objects.order_by('-created_date')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.views += 1
        self.save()
        kwargs['views'] = self.views
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

class PostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = “post”
    template_name = ‘detail.html’

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.views += 1
        self.save()
        #Aqui realmente no se que retornar
```

Lo pude hacer funcionar con function based views pero no es lo que yo quiero realmente, quisiera poder hacerlo con CBV.

**Esto es lo que quiero lograr, pero hecho en la clase generica**

```
def post_detail(request, post_pk):
    post = Post.get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_pk)
    post.views += 1
    post.save()
    return render(request, ‘detail.html’, {‘post’: post }
```

Perdon si doy poca informacion o la pregunta esta mal formulada, soy relativamente nuevo.

Comment: Hola. No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer. Eso que tienes ahí es un `ListView`, ¿estás tratando de incrementar las vistas de cada Post en la lista? ¿No sería mejor incrementarlo en la vista de detalle usando un `DetailView`? Es decir, solo cuando entras al detalle de un Post, entonces le incrementas en 1.

Comment: para que retorne el context es con...context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs).....context['extra_param'] = 'test'.... return context...

Comment: te sugiero usar esta herramienta para crear un contador de visitas: https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount

Comment: @César probé en una vista DetailView, pero me sigue dando el mismo error, has no attribute 'views', es un codigo basado en un tutorial y lo fui modificando a lo que yo quería lograr pero no estoy entendiendo si es similar a lo que intento hacer

Comment: @Tegito123 estoy intentando hacer el contador por mi cuenta, pero voy a probar el hitcount, gracias!

Comment: @FedericoToledo actualiza tu código para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @César ya esta actualizado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente encontre una solución, y estaba cometiendo el error de usar get_context_data(), no necesitaba agregar datos a mi vista PostDetailView, si no que necesitaba realizar cambios luego de ser llamada la vista, y para eso django utiliza get_object, que es el que devuelve el objeto del modelo, y en ese método solo hay que sobrescribir lo que se quiere hacer, en mi caso aumentar las visitas en 1, y luego devuelvo el objeto modificado

```
class PostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
model = Post
template_name = "detail.html"

    def get_object(self):
        post = super().get_object()
        #Aumentar en 1 las visitas
        post.views +=1
        post.save()
        return post
```

Luego en el template utiliza post como context_object_name de la clase genérica

Answer (score 2):

Federico, creo que estás un poco confundido. El atributo `views` no le pertenece a la clase de la vista, le pertene al modelo. Con esto, lo único que tendrías que hacer en tu vista de detalle es:

```
class PostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "detail.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object.views += 1
        self.object.save()
        # Deja que la clase se encargue de lo demás
        return super(PostDetailView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Cuando usas un `DetailView` tienes acceso a la instancia en cuestión (el `post`) usando `self.object`. Repito: no confundas el `self`, que es la clase misma, con el `self.object` que hace referencia a una instancia del modelo o registro en la base de datos.

Comment: César, me sigue dando el mismo tipo de error, PostDetailView object has no attribute 'object'